# Delete the first 10 largest regular files using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to delete the first largest regular files from the given directory, but it doesn't work for files which contain whitespace caracters.

**My code** (it works if the files doesn't contain whitespace caracters):

```
find mydir -type f -exec du -ahb {} + | sort -n -r | cut -f2 | head -n 10 | xargs rm -i
```

**I also tried this**, but it gives an error message:

```
find mydir -type f -exec du -ahb {} + -print 0 | sort -n -r | cut -f2 | head -n 10 | xargs -0 rm -i
```

Comment: I also tried with `-print0`  but it doesn't work. With a single `find` command the problem is that I can't give the option `-i` to the delete command which promts before every removal.

Comment: In your second try it looks like you tried to use `-print0`, which prints records separated with NUL bytes rather than linefeeds. It's a common workaround to space parsing problems, however it won't work if what you want to parse is the result of  your `du` execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work at least with GNU coreutils 8.25 and newer :

```
find mydir -type f -exec du -0b {} + | sort -znr | cut -zf2 | head -zn 10 |  xargs -0pn 1 rm
```

I made sure every command handled and outputted NUL bytes (`\0`) separated records rather than linefeed separated records :

- `du` outputs NUL-separated records with `-0`
- `sort`, `cut` and `head` handle and output NUL-separated records with `-z`
- `xargs` handles NUL-separated records with `-0`

Additionally, I removed the interactive mode of `rm` and asked `xargs` to handle that instead (`-p`), because `xargs` didn't provide a prompt to `rm` when invoking it. I had to limit the number of parameters given at once to `rm` to 1 for this to work (`xargs`' `-n 1` parameter). There might be a way to preserve the `-i` and provide `rm` with an interface to your prompt, but I don't know how.

Last point : I removed `du`'s `-h`uman-readable mode because it would have made the sort often fail and it didn't serve any purpose since the filesizes were never displayed to an human.

Comment: What version of head and cut have `-z` option?

Comment: It works, but the problem is that I have to delete only regular files and this command tries to delete directories too

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert I've updated it to select files only ; the `find` was indeed necessary to select files only

Comment: @123 Gnu-coreutils 8.25 it seems ; I've added that info to my answer, thanks for reminding me that not everyone might have those options available.

Comment: The prompts don't wait for the answers so it doesn't delete any file

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert that's what I noticed too, and I don't know why it happens. I honestly just adapted your first commandline to use NUL bytes rather than linefeeds and hoped it only didn't work on my side. I don't see why using NUL would change prompting behaviour ; did your first version work when there was no filenames with spaces? Anyway I'll look into it

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert Yeah it's a problem with your `xargs` invocation. I think using `xargs -p` might do the trick (although it won't be `rm -i`'s message anymore, you'll have the same functionality). Working on it.

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert updated. That's not the prettiest, but it works. Reply with  `y` or `n` to `xargs`' prompt

Comment: @FogarasiNorbert you're welcome, it's was an interesting question to reply to :)